# the env.py file keeps dispearing from GitPod workspace

Tags: github, gitpod

I cant commit the changes when I recreate the file, as I get the follwing message:

**"On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean"**

Everything else can be commited...

Once I close the workspace and come back to continue working, the env.py is gone...

I can only fix it, by rebuilding the missing file... everytime I log back into the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was in the gitignore file. I removed that entry and the problem was solved.